# Is there a way to automatically expire RSS feed links in podcast software after a specified period?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, rss

If the user linked the podcast feed URL to podcast software like Spotify, iTunes and etc. So the question is can we expire this feed URL based on something?

If the user adds a link to Spotify today and starts listening to this podcast, after 1-year the user shouldn't have access to this podcast, So is there any way to do that??